# Stuck in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a simple code like this:

```
try {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < size) {
        System.out.println("i is" + i);
        if (someCondition) {
            System.out.println("do sth");
            someCondition = true;
            i++;
            System.out.println("i is" + i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("doAnotherThing");
            someCondition = true;
            i++;
            System.out.println("i is" + i);
        }
    }
} catch(Exception){

}
```

This code snippet's output is:

```
i is 0
do sth
i is 1
i is 0
doAnotherThing
i is 1
```

It should have increase I, than break while loop but it doesn't. Do you have any opinion about this issue? I am working on this issue since 5 hours, maybe I am missing something. I will be glad if you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I wanted to simplify things, but appearantly it didn't work :) OK Here is the real code:

```
public void (Analyzer analyzer){
    try {    
        int i=0;
        while (i < analyzer.size()) {
            System.out.println("i is" + i);
            Object anInstance = analyzer.getObject().get(i);
            if (anInstance.getDatabaseCreated()) { //this comes from another class and is //false in the first place                         
                dropObject(analyzer.getId(),i); // removes object
                createAnInstance(analyzer.getId(), i, anInstance.getTypes()); //creates another instance                         
                anInstance.markCreated();

                Query query = createInsertQuery(analyzer.getId(), i, anInstance.getTypes());                          

                for (int j = 0; j < anInstance.rowCount(); j++) {
                    insertRow(query, anInstance.getTypes(), anInstance.getRow(j));
                }
                i++;
                System.out.println("i is" + i);
            } else {                            
                createAnInstance(analyzer.getId(), i, anInstance.getTypes());
                anInstance.markCreated();
                Query query = createInsertQuery(analyzer.getId(), i, anInstance.getTypes());
                for (int j = 0; j < anInstance.rowCount(); j++) {
                    insertRow(query, anInstance.getTypes(), anInstance.getRow(j));                                   
                }
                i++;
                System.out.println("i is" + i);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AnalyzerService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like something is calling this code multiple times...

Comment: Does this even compile? It looks like you're missing a closing brace before `else`.

Comment: The code you've presented won't compile - you've got an `else` with no closing brace before it, and no single-statement `if` before it either. Please present a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: This clearly isn't your real code, not least because it won't compile. Please quote your ***real code***. Code edited to make it hypothetical that doesn't actually replicate the problem just wastes everyone's time (including yours). If you must edit the code, ensure the edited result actually compiles and replicates the problem.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. How can the code at some point print "doAnotherThing" if someCondition is never false?

Comment: Can you please specify what would be the expected output of this code?

Comment: this is being called by something else.  where is size defined?

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to do mate?

Comment: If you're too lazy to type in your real code, we should equally be unbothered to help you.

Comment: It was not because I am lazy to write the real code (infact I think writing the real code is sometimes laziness), I just wanted to simplify things a little bit, apperantely it didn't work. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in order to get the output you have given there must be 2 separate calls being made to the method (which in your code snippet above has no name).  It seems the method is called, i is set to 0, the loop starts and the first condition is true.  The loop then ends (because analyzer.size() is 1, or maybe an exception???) then somewhere else in your code you are calling this method again.  Again i is set to 0 but this time the first condition is false (a result of the first call to the method???) so you go through the else instead.  Again the loop ends after 1 iteration, either because analyzer.size() is 1 or an exception is thrown).

Comment: You were right, this method is being called twice.  Since I did not write the code myself in the first place, I did not realize this mistake.. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the `someCondition` to true in both `if` and `else` ? Also, check if the `someCondition` is resetting the value of `i` to `0` or something. Without knowing what the `someCondition` is, it is difficult to guess. But if it is a function taking the value of `i` as a a parameter, I will check that.

Comment: There was a neccessity to reset someCondition inside the loops. But the problem was not there. The problem was this method has been called twice from other classes. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code's bogus - the bracketing doesn't line up even.  As written this would work assuming you initialized the size variable, otherwise size might be huge (random integer number like 384923492348) and it would do alot of iterations.  Can you fix the code up if you want a better answer (just copy paste? :) )

Comment: I did not wanted to bother people with some nonsense code, that's why I rewrite the code for SO. Apperantely people here prefer real codes. Anyway, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `dropObject` is altering `analyzer.size()` and that the size of the latter was `1` in the first place.

Comment: That wouldn't explain the output of i is 1, followed by i is 0, given that the only operation on i is to increment it.

Answer (score 0):

It's apparent that `analyzer.size()` is mutating. Since I don't know the rest of the source, I can't know for sure what's causing it. Here's a list of possible culprits:

- analyzer.size
- analyzer.getObject().get
- anInstance.getDatabaseCreated
- dropObject
- markCreated
- analyzer.getId
- analyzer.getTypes
- anInstance.getRow
- anInstance.getTypes
- insertRow

If you don't need to worry about what happens when you *add* lines to the query, you could simply cache analyzer size ahead of time, but you might run into trouble as it looks like you are removing some values while simultaneously adding others. If this doesn't matter, though, it is as simple as:

```
int i=0;
int sz = analyzer.size()
while (i < sz) {
```

Also, I noticed that there was a lot of copied and pasted code. Bad deal. Your entire while loop could be:

```
// you left out the function name!
public void theNamelessOne(Analyzer analyzer){
    try {    
        int i=0;
        while (i < analyzer.size()) {
            System.out.println("i is" + i);
            // the only time you should really use an article ("a", "an", "the" 
            // or equivalent) in a method or vaeriable name is when referencing 
            // "the doctor" or "the wabbit". since there is only one "the doctor"
            // and this is not an Elmer Fudd related instance, you may want to 
            // remove it.
            Object anInstance = analyzer.getObject().get(i);
            if (anInstance.getDatabaseCreated()) { 
                dropObject(analyzer.getId(),i);
            } 
            createAnInstance(analyzer.getId(), i, anInstance.getTypes());
            anInstance.markCreated();
            Query query = createInsertQuery(  analyzer.getId(), 
                                              i, 
                                              anInstance.getTypes());
            for (int j = 0; j < anInstance.rowCount(); j++) {
                insertRow(query, anInstance.getTypes(), anInstance.getRow(j));
            }
            i++;
            System.out.println("i is" + i);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(
            AnalyzerService.class.getName()
        ).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Your code is cleaner than mine, clearly and I will keep it as reference for future use. But the code that I provided is alo working. I found the cause of the error: this function is being called twice. Since I did not write the code, I didn't realize this mistake. Anyway, thanks a lot for your long explanation.